# Free good quality vocal/choir sound fonts

Tags: data-request, music, audio, creative-commons

I am looking for some good quality (possibly large sized) **choir** or **vocal** [soundfonts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SoundFont). They should be **free**. The notes should be performed by **male or children** singer(s). Is there any such free fonts available?

Comment: are you asking for sheetmusic?

Comment: @albert Nope. I am looking for soundfonts. Something like this: http://www.freedrumkits.net/sound-fonts/7-choirs . These are not too high quality, so I was wondering if there are any free HQ ones available.